# How can i Update container image with imagedigest parameter in aws fargate cluster with aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-fargate

I have running my cluster and task is running.

My need is want to update container image in running task in cluster how to do?

My Image is with latest tag and every time any new changes come will push to ecr on latest tag.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying with the tag latest isn't a best practice because you loose a lot of visibility into what you are doing (e.g. scale out events where you deploy more tasks as part of a service will all end up using `LATEST` but will be effectively running different versions of the code, etc.).

This pontificating aside, you didn't say if you started your task(s) as standalone using the `run-task` API or if you started your task(s) as part of a service.

If the former, you need to [stop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/stop-task.html) your task and [run](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html) it again. If the latter, you need to [redeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html) your service using the `--force-new-deployment` flag.